# Lumen environments definition

Tags: php, lumen

I have used Lumen (Laravel based framework) to design my API.

I must manage two environments (production, local). I tried to put these lines in my **bootstrap/app.php** file :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local'         => array('my-system'),
    'production'    => array('prod-system'),
));
```

But, when I try to execute **php artisan serve** it gives me the following error :

```
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::detectEnvironment()
```

How can I define my environments in Lumen ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `.env` file? Check out [Lumen docs](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation#environment-configuration).

Comment: Yes, I know this way but I must define my environment according to the system.

Comment: Can you point me to where the `detectEnvironment` method is defined , as I am looking into https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/69158e27539b4b6a1470262891866581b9061ff6/src/helpers.php I only see `environment` which will decide if it does exist in the .env file or not

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to define an environment conditionally based on hostname the following should work:

```
$env = str_is('production-hostname', gethostname()) ? 'production' : 'local';
putenv("APP_ENV=$env");
```

In lumen this should go in your bootstrap/app.php file.